# accessing protected properties from java subpackages

Tags: java, package

suppose I have package J

moreover I create a new folder in J hence it becomes a subpackage of J, let's say it's J.E

suppose I have a class in J named H with protected properties, and another class named T in J.E

can class T access the protected properties of H?

Comment: what did the compiler tell you when you tried?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sub-packages are useful only as an organizational concept. They can never be used for access control; no access relationships exist between a parent package and a child package.

From the Java Language Specification:

> 7.1   Package Members
>
> ...
>
> The hierarchical naming structure for
>   packages is intended to be convenient
>   for organizing related packages in a
>   conventional manner, but has no
>   significance in itself other than the
>   prohibition against a package having a
>   subpackage with the same simple name
>   as a top level type (§7.6) declared in
>   that package. **There is no special
>   access relationship** between a package
>   named oliver and another package named
>   oliver.twist, or between packages
>   named evelyn.wood and evelyn.waugh.

In the context of your problem, class T cannot access the protected properties of H unless T is a subclass of H.